# ArrayList no Carga mas de un Valor JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, jframe, imprimir

necesito ayuda para un trabajo de Jframe, donde tengo una clase Empleado con un ArrayList, una clase Persona con un par de datos y la clase del Jframe. El problema es que debo capturar los datos de un empleado del Jframe y mandarlos a Persona, donde luego el ArrayList en Empleado captura los datos, todo esto con la finalidad que luego de haber cargado todos los empleados pueda imprimir los datos de cada uno que se almacenaron en el ArrayList. A continuacion dejo la clase Empleado.

```
package modelo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import static modelo.Persona.Apellido;
import static modelo.Persona.Dni;
import static modelo.Persona.Legajo;
import static modelo.Persona.Sexo;
import static modelo.Persona.SueldoLiquidacion;

public class Empleado {


    ArrayList<Persona> lista = new ArrayList<>();  

    public void agregar(){

        lista.add(new Persona(Legajo, Apellido, Sexo, Dni,SueldoLiquidacion));       
    }
    public String mostrar(){
      Persona p;                  
     String datos= ""; 

    for( int i=0; i < lista.size(); i++ ) { 
    p = (Persona) lista.get(i); 
        datos += p.toString();  
      }      
        return datos;

    }       
}
```

Aqui va la clase Persona

```
package modelo;

public class Persona {

    public static int Legajo=0;
    public static String Apellido="";
    public static String Sexo="";
    public static int Dni=0;
    public static double SueldoLiquidacion =0;

    public Persona() {
    }


    public Persona(int Legajo, String Apellido, String Sexo, int Dni, double SueldoLiquidacion) {
        this.Legajo = Legajo;
        this.Apellido = Apellido;
        this.Sexo = Sexo;
        this.Dni = Dni;
        this.SueldoLiquidacion = SueldoLiquidacion;
    }

    public int getLegajo() {
        return Legajo;
    }

    public void setLegajo(int Legajo) {
        this.Legajo = Legajo;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return Apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String Apellido) {
        this.Apellido = Apellido;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return Sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String Sexo) {
        this.Sexo = Sexo;
    }

    public int getDni() {
        return Dni;
    }

    public void setDni(int Dni) {
        this.Dni = Dni;
    }

    public double getSueldoLiquidacion() {
        return SueldoLiquidacion;
    }

    public void setSueldoLiquidacion(double SueldoLiquidacion) {
        this.SueldoLiquidacion = SueldoLiquidacion;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n"+"Legajo=" + Legajo + " Apellido=" + Apellido + " Sexo=" + Sexo + " Dni=" + Dni + " SueldoLiquidacion=" + SueldoLiquidacion;
    }


}
```

Aqui la clase del Jframe y su codigo principal donde se cargan datos y se llama al metodo agregar (ArrayList)

```
package vista;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import modelo.Empleado;
import modelo.Operario;
import static modelo.Operario.SueldoLiqOper;
import modelo.Persona;
import modelo.Vendedor;
import static modelo.Vendedor.SueldoLiqVend;

public class Interfaz extends javax.swing.JFrame {

 public int HorasMensuales = 0;
 public int ValorHora = 0;
 public double SueldoBase=0;
 public double MontoVenta=0;
 public double ComisionVenta=0;
 public double TotalSueldos =0;


  Empleado obj = new Empleado(); 
  Persona obj1 = new Persona();
  Operario obj2 = new Operario();
  Vendedor obj3 = new Vendedor();



    public Interfaz() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);      
    }


    private void OpcionOperarioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
      if(OpcionOperario.isSelected()){
          bloquear();
      }else{habilitar();}
    }                                              


    private void bloquear (){        
    txtMontoVend.setEnabled(false);
    txtPorcentaje.setEnabled(false);
    txtSueldo.setEnabled(false);
    txtCantHs.setEnabled(true);
    txtValorhs.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void habilitar (){
    txtCantHs.setEnabled(false);
    txtValorhs.setEnabled(false);
    txtMontoVend.setEnabled(true);
    txtPorcentaje.setEnabled(true);
    txtSueldo.setEnabled(true);
    }


    private void RegistrarEmpleadoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
          if(txtLegajo.getText().equals("") || txtApellido.getText().equals("") || textDni.getText().equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Complete todos los campos");
        }else if(!OpcionOperario.isSelected() && !OpcionVendedor.isSelected()){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Marque Operario o Vendedor");
        };
        if(OpcionOperario.isSelected() && !txtCantHs.getText().equals("") && !txtValorhs.getText().equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro Exitoso");
        }else if (OpcionOperario.isSelected() && (txtCantHs.getText().equals("") || txtValorhs.getText().equals(""))){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Complete todos los campos");
        }

        if(OpcionVendedor.isSelected() && !txtMontoVend.getText().equals("") && !txtSueldo.getText().equals("") && !txtPorcentaje.getText().equals(""))
        {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro Exitoso");
        }else if (OpcionVendedor.isSelected() && (txtMontoVend.getText().equals("") || txtSueldo.getText().equals("") || txtPorcentaje.getText().equals("")))
        {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Complete todos los campos");}

        **obj1.Legajo = Integer.parseInt(txtLegajo.getText());
        obj1.Apellido = txtApellido.getText();
        obj1.Sexo = ComboSexo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        obj1.Dni = Integer.parseInt(textDni.getText());

        if(OpcionOperario.isSelected()){        
        SueldoOper();
        obj1.SueldoLiquidacion = (double) SueldoLiqOper;
        }else {            
            SueldoVend();
            obj1.SueldoLiquidacion = (double) SueldoLiqVend;
        }

        obj.agregar();
        limpiar();**

    }                                                 


    public void limpiar(){
    txtLegajo.setText("");
    txtApellido.setText("");
    ComboSexo.setSelectedIndex(0);
    textDni.setText("");
    GrupoBoton.clearSelection();
    txtCantHs.setText("");
    txtMontoVend.setText("");
    txtSueldo.setText("");
    txtPorcentaje.setText("");
    txtValorhs.setText("");
    txtSueldoLiq.setText("");

    }


    public void SueldoVend(){
    SueldoBase = Integer.parseInt(txtSueldo.getText());
    MontoVenta = Integer.parseInt(txtMontoVend.getText());
    ComisionVenta = Integer.parseInt(txtPorcentaje.getText());
    obj3.ComisionVenta = ComisionVenta;
    obj3.MontoVenta = MontoVenta;
    obj3.SueldoBase = SueldoBase;
    SueldoLiqVend = obj3.SueldoBase+obj3.MontoVenta*obj3.ComisionVenta/100;
    txtSueldoLiq.setText(String.valueOf(SueldoLiqVend));
    TotalSueldos += SueldoLiqVend;
    txtTotalSueldos.setText(String.valueOf(TotalSueldos));
    }

    public void SueldoOper (){
    ValorHora = Integer.parseInt(txtValorhs.getText());
    HorasMensuales = Integer.parseInt(txtCantHs.getText());
    obj2.ValorHora = ValorHora;    
    obj2.HorasMensuales = HorasMensuales;
    SueldoLiqOper = (obj2.ValorHora*obj2.HorasMensuales);
    txtSueldoLiq.setText(String.valueOf(SueldoLiqOper));
    TotalSueldos += SueldoLiqOper;
    txtTotalSueldos.setText(String.valueOf(TotalSueldos));
    }
```

El codigo no esta completo porque es muy largo, pero esta la parte principal donde se encuentra el enfoque. El problema que ocupo es el siguiente

[image: Al ingresar un empleado y mostrar los datos todo esta bien]

[image: Al ingresar un segundo empleado y mostrar los datos, se repite 2 veces los datos del segundo empleado ingresado]

Por lo tanto hay un problema en cuanto a imprimir el arraylist o en cuanto a la carga de datos, por lo que si alguien puede desifrar el error seria de gran ayuda. Para simplificar las cosas lo principal esta en mirar la clase Empleado y el Jframe en el metodo Registrar Empleado donde se mueven los datos a Persona y se llama a obj.agregar();

Comment: Y que es lo que no funciona?, porque errores no aparecen en el codigo segun entiendo... y veo que te imprime la informacion, que es aquello que no cuadra?

Comment: El problema es que deben imprimirse los datos de cada empleado cargado y se estan imprimiendo los datos solamente del ultimo empleado cargado y repetidas la cantidad de empleados.

Legajo, apellido, sexo, dni....
Legajo, apellido, sexo, dni.... 

Esto debe ser diferente y no igual como en la imagen

Answer (score -1):

Aquí lo que ocurre es que tienes todas las propiedades de tu clase Persona como `static` o sea como variables de clase. Eso significa que todos los objectos que estén instanciados de la Clase Persona van a tener los valores que hayas asignado a lo último, porque son estáticos (es decir, compartidos por todos las instancias de esa clase).
Cámbialas a variables de objeto (sin static) y empezarás a resolver el problema.

Comment: Más allá de esto, tu código es muy confuso. Si hay una relación entre las clases Persona, Empleado, Operario, Vendedor, entonces deberían tener una jerarquía de clases. Una Persona es un Empleado, que a su vez puede ser Operario o Vendedor.

Y por favor, ponle nombres más descriptivos a tus variables, obj1, obj2 son los peores nombres posibles para variables, no explican nada y hacen que sea mucho más difícil entender el código.

Comment: Porfavor lee [answer].

Comment: Perdón, cuál es el problema con mi respuesta?

Comment: Que no contiene ningun codigo explicativo relacionado a la respuesta y le falta detalles, se considera de baja calidad responder mayoritariamente con opiniones y no con codigo, debe haber un equilibrio entre ambos, en tu caso lo unico que veo de codigo es que hablas de la palabra reservada static, no lo digo yo, lo dicen la mayoria de usuarios de hecho el manual [answer] te dice justo esto que estoy diciendo. de hecho cambiar o no a statica no resuelve el problema (dices que las propiedades static no pueden ser cambiadas lo cual es incorrecto).

Comment: No leíste bien mi respuesta, dónde digo yo que las propiedades estaticas no pueden ser cambiadas?
Tener las propiedades de un clase del domino como static es incorrecto, porque como digo en la respuesta, todos los objectos instanciados van a tener los mismos valores en esas propiedades, de hecho ese es el motivo porque el OP vé los datos repetidos, porque los esta sacando de las variables estáticas que son compartidas por todos los objetos de la clase. Cada vez que hace new Persona(...) (cuando lo agrega a la lista), esta sobreescribiendo todas esas variables estáticas.